# Where is a list of keycode values to use in DarkSouls.ini?

Tags: dark-souls, keyboard

Dark Souls does not allow binding of many common keys via the user interface. There are guides for the number keys, but no guides for other keys. Specifically, I have a Dvorak keyboard, and would like to bind the ['], [,], [.], and [;] keys. What are the scancodes for these keys to use in the DarkSouls.ini file? Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

An user on [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2906393) posted a link to [keyboard codes for ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html). He tested some key numberings in the .ini file and they worked. So you might be able to use the key codes from ActionScript to configure Dark Souls.